# How did Ocean's Thirteen made their profit

Tags: oceans-thirteen

I'm not really getting how Daniel and his friends made any profit from their hustle. Sure, the Chinese guy won in roulette and Daniel and Rusty made some minor profit at the dice table but that surely didn't suffice to stack up to enough money to pay Terry Benedict and to refund their own losses that they made as investment to the project of breaking Willie Bank.

**These questions refer to other questions that I asked if you know an answer to those refer to my profile and feel free to share your knowledge on these too:**

2. At the end of the movie Reuben is handed a paper with the words "... prime real estate at the south end of the Strip". I think this refers to the Bank Hotel but how did Daniel restore his share of the hotel? Sure they ruined Willie Bank but he surely wouldn't sell Reuben's former shares back to the man who just conned him?
3. How did Rusty convince the female concierge to participate in their hustle? He says: "As soon as I said the words general manager and Macau, she was in". What does that even mean and how did that serve as motivation for the woman to cooperate?

Note: I'm no native speaker please correct any spelling mistake :-)

Comment: You have at least 3 questions in there which makes this too broad. Try splitting the post into 3 **separate** question posts that can be individually answered.

Comment: It's done. Forgott about that sorry

Comment: No...remove the other questions from this post..and start NEW posts for the others.

Comment: How about no.. the question is clear and the rules do not forbid referencing other questions

Comment: It's too broad if you are asking THREE questions in one. That makes it off-topic...it's not about clarity.

Comment: See https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/multiple-question-on-same-movie-at-a-time-should-be-in-one-single-question-or-i

Comment: ..and https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/thou-shalt-not-put-two-questions-in-one-post?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I'll be brief.

To answer your first question, in the third movie, Ocean's Thirteen, Their whole plan was **not** make a profit, but hurt Willie Banks. Banks' actions made Reuben almost die and Danny and his gang did all they did just as a revenge. Bank's most valuable things were his hotel, his diamond award, his diamond awards showcase, his customers, his most trusted employee (Abigail Sponder). And Danny and the gang hit them all, they destroyed all those valuable things to Bank. That was their intention. not earning any profit.

For the second question, I think your question already has the answer. Danny conned Bank and took everything that he conned from Reuben.

For third,

> As soon as I said the words general manager and Macau, she was in

That means that Rusty convinced her that He can get her as a general manager in Banks' Macau hotel. in Vegas, she has just a minor position. So she'd definitely go for an opportunity like that. That's how Rusty conned her. In the end, whether she gets the position or not is not clear.

`A little note, this question has way more broad area to cover, so from now on, you should be careful on asking questions. It makes others easy to help you out. consider it.`

Comment: you should give a reason for downvote, don't you think? answering a question is much more difficult than just clicking on down-vote arrow.

Comment: Thanks for sharing and yes I will stick to your suggestions in the future. I don't get the downvote either, it's a reasonable answer

Comment: If this provides the answer you were looking for, marking them as accepted will help others. Glad I could help, nah I dun mind down-votes. They do what they do and I do what I do.